# Python: extracts the same values across years

Tags: python

question: Write a function that extracts the same values across years and calculates the differences between consecutive values to show if number of births is increasing or decreasing. For example, how did the number of births on Saturday change each year between 1994 and 2003?

I have extracted data day of the week wise and year wise too (see the codes below). However, I need it as: Year / day of the week / number of births. After getting this output I want to see day wise change in years (Births on Sundays in 1995 compared to births on Sundays in 1994).

Source: (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fivethirtyeight/data/master/births/US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.csv)

for example:

```
         {1994, 1, 124567,
          1994, 2, 524652...
      ....2003, 7, 452456}
```

...earlier work...

**code: DAY OF THE WEEK WISE**

```
def dow_births(lst_of_lsts):
    birth_per_day = dict()

    for row in lst_of_lsts:
        day_of_week = row[3]
        births = row[4]

        if day_of_week in birth_per_day:
            birth_per_day[day_of_week] += births
        else:
            birth_per_day[day_of_week] = births

    return birth_per_day  

cdc_day_births = dow_births(cdc_list)
```

**input:**

```
cdc_day_births
```

**output:**

```
{1: 5789166,
 2: 6446196,
 3: 6322855,
 4: 6288429,
 5: 6233657,
 6: 4562111,
 7: 4079723}
```

**code: YEAR WISE**

```
def calc_counts(data, column):
    sum_dict = dict()

    for row in data:
        column_value = row[column]
        births = row[4]
        if column_value in sum_dict:
            sum_dict[column_value] += births
        else:
            sum_dict[column_value] = births

    return sum_dict
```

**Input:**

```
cdc_year_births
```

**Output:**

```
{1994: 3952767,
 1995: 3899589,
 1996: 3891494,
 1997: 3880894,
 1998: 3941553,
 1999: 3959417,
 2000: 4058814,
 2001: 4025933,
 2002: 4021726,
 2003: 4089950}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want the sum of the births in a given day of the week aggregated by year.

This should get you what you want

```
from collections import defaultdict

saturday_births = defaultdict(list)                                                           
for row in data:                                                                           
    if int(row[3]) == 6:  # day of the week
        # Create a dict where year is the key and the births are the values                                         
        saturday_births[int(row[0])].append(int(row[4]))
        # Aggregate the values with sum()                                                                                                
        sum_births_per_year = [[year, sum(births)] for year,births in saturday_births.items()]
```

Output:

```
[[1994, 474732],
[1995, 459580],
[1996, 456261], 
[1997, 450840], 
[1998, 453776], 
[1999, 449985], 
[2000, 469794], 
[2001, 453928], 
[2002, 445770], 
[2003, 447445]]
```

Comment: Thanks holak.. I will try this and revert.